# Should the names of computer programs and libraries be preceded by an article?

Tags: articles, definite-article, indefinite-article, proper-nouns

If I want to refer to a computer program, like, e.g. Internet Explorer, Firefox, Google Chrome, etc., do I need an article (definite/indefinite?) ?

> (1) use **the** Internet Explorer, use **the** Firefox, use **the** Google Chrome
>
> (2) use **an** Internet Explorer, use **a** Firefox, use **a** Google Chrome
>
> (3) use Internet Explorer, use Firefox, use Google Chrome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just like with other names (e.g. for persons or countries), don't use an article.